# Drop the date from a matplotlib time series plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a simple time series plot in Pandas, that can be emulated by the following code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : np.random.rand(1440).cumsum()}, index = pd.date_range('1/1/2015', periods=1440, freq='1min'))

df2.A.plot()
```

Which generates the following graph:
[image]

My problem is that the date displayed is not relevant to the graph itself and I wish to remove it and leave only the time series on the x axis.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use `matplotlib.dates` and its `HourLocator` to set the date/time formatting:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dates

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : np.random.rand(1440).cumsum()}, index = pd.date_range('1/1/2015', periods=1440, freq='1min'))

df2.A.plot()
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.HourLocator())
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Just the HourLocator worked for me, the formatter gave an error.